# get app icon from window id in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos

I am looking for a way to get the application icon from a window id in cocoa. Do you have any pointer for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, use `CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray()` to get the PID of the owning process (`kCGWindowOwnerPID`). If this is 10.6, you can then use `+[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:]` to get the application object and then use `-icon`.

Before 10.6, you need to use `GetProcessForPID()` to switch to a PSN, use `GetProcessBundleLocation()` to get the location of the bundle, switch the FSRef into a path string, and then use `-[NSWorkspace iconForFile:]` to get the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Rob Napier's answer is correct.

In the latest api and in swift language, it should be like this:

```
let runningApp = NSRunningApplication(processIdentifier: pid_t(the_process_id))
let icon = runningApp?.icon
```